# SQL:Atithmeic overflow error, casting and try casting not solving the problem

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting, overflow, numeric

I am currently working on a solution to update a variable in large quantity. However I am running into a problem. I am getting the follow error while executing my query:

> Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric

The query:

```
update Table_Name 
SET Percentage = CAST((((tn.variable_1 - tn.variable_2 ) / (tn.variable_3 - tn.variable_2 ))  * 100.0) AS numeric(14, 4))
FROM Table_Name tn
WHERE Percentage IS NULL
AND tn.variable_1 is not null
AND tn.variable_2 is not null
AND tn.variable_3 is not null
GO
```

The percentage column is defined as a decimal with a size of 14 and a after comma(,) size of 4. This means it is defined as Percentage decimal(14,4). I have tried changing to cast to decimal (14,4), but this doesn't seem to affect it either way.

Variations I have tried:
1

```
update Table_Name 
SET Percentage = TRY_CAST((((tn.variable_1 - tn.variable_2 ) / (tn.variable_3 - tn.variable_2 ))  * 100.0) AS numeric(14, 4))
FROM Table_Name tn
WHERE Percentage IS NULL
AND tn.variable_1 is not null
AND tn.variable_2 is not null
AND tn.variable_3 is not null
GO
```

2

```
update Table_Name 
SET Percentage = TRY_CAST((TRY_CAST(((tn.variable_1 - tn.variable_2 ) / (tn.variable_3 - tn.variable_2 )))  * 100.0) AS numeric(14, 4))
FROM Table_Name tn
WHERE Percentage IS NULL
AND tn.variable_1 is not null
AND tn.variable_2 is not null
AND tn.variable_3 is not null
GO
```

I know for a fact that the first version works in specific data set's but, it not updating in the live enviroment because of the above error. I am kinda at a loss of what I can stil do.

Comment: Presumably the *result* of the calculation does not fit in the column.  You have left out of the question how `percentage` is defined.

Comment: it is defined as decimal(14,4)
I've edited the post to reflect this. Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: Please check if wrapping your calculation in `NULLIF()` changes the outcome, especially if `tn.variable_3 - tn.variable_2` could result in zero.

Comment: Unfortunately, wrapping the calculations in NULIF didn't work. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: What are the datatypes of the columns used in your calculation? And a side note - if this works in your dev / test environment but not in your production environment, then you have some rather serious deficiencies in the quantity of realistic data available in those environments.

Comment: @SMor I agree on that last part.This has been a complaint from the DEV team for weeks, we've outlined solutions to this, but the organisation that hired the company I work for wouldn't budge on certain protocols and the other solutions takes weeks of burecreatic bs to work through.

As far as the columns go. They're all decimal(14,4) for type, size and decimal size.